# Difference between categorial factor as main effect or random factor

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I am analysing data where I assess the effects of drug (3 levels),session and value on some external variable y. When I use fitlme and specify drug as a categorical variable, I get two estimates for drug (which makes sense because the two other categories are used as a reference category). However, tbh I dont quite understand whats the difference between y~value+session+drug and y~value+session+(1|drug). In both cases an intercept for the different levels of drug is modelled, isn`t it?
Also, if I assume that value differs per drug, does it make sense to include a random slope as y~value+session+drug+value|drug? Is my understandig correct that it does not since the intercept for drug is modelled twice and I would need to write y~value+session+drug+value-1|drug?
Every help would be very much appreciated,

Laurie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are specifically interested in the "effect" of the drug, it does not make sense to include it as a random factor. It should be a fixed effect only. Also, since it has only 3 levels, this means that if you were to include it as random you would be asking the software to estimate a variance for it based on only 3 observations, which also does not make much sense.

Because of this, random slopes are not relevant.

You should fit a multivariable regression model, not a mixed effects model. Something like:

```
y ~ drug*value + session
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! However I do have a follow-up question to the second part of my question: I assume that the effect of value on y is different under the three levels of drug. Isn`t that exactly what would be estimated with a random slope?

Comment: Maybe I should specify that value is a continuous variable and y as well.

Comment: Also I do have thousands of obervations for drug, but they can only take 3 levels. If I do 1|drug I get one intercept per drug, don`t I?

Comment: You're welcome. It doesn't matter that you have thousands of observations. Since there are only 3 drugs, there are only 3 unique observations for `drug` when you treat it as random.

Comment: Thanks! but by using value|drug I use value as random and group them by drug, no?

Comment: *": I assume that the effect of value on y is different under the three levels of drug. Isn`t that exactly what would be estimated with a random slope?"*. It can be interpreted like that, but you don't have enough levels of drug. Also you will be treating the random effects as normally distributed, which may not be realistic, nor provide useful inferences. A better approach is to fit the interaction between value and drug as a fixed effect.

Comment: I would suggest the model: `y~drug*value+session` and you may want to centre `value` about it's mean

Comment: I did that! Thanks you really helped me a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome :)